# java System.loadLibrary() load failed in mac, but System.load() works fine

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I code a JNI demo in mac, I found java System.loadLibrary() load failed in mac, but System.load() works fine.I have tried some way to solve this problem, but didn't work, can someone give me advice.there are ways I have tried:
**1、set "-Djava.library.path=/Users/wang/javaPrj/AndroidPushServer/out/production" in IDEA "debug-Configurations-VM Options",the running log as follow:**  */Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Djava.library.path=/Users/wang/javaPrj/AndroidPushServer/out/production -Didea.launcher.port=7532 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar ... /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.yuwan.androidpushserver.server
/Users/wang/javaPrj/AndroidPushServer/out/production

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no push in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)

    ...

    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:123)
Process finished with exit code 1*
**the libpush.so is exists in that directory:**
*lxr:production wang$ pwd

/Users/wang/javaPrj/AndroidPushServer/out/production
lxr:production wang$ 
lxr:production wang$ ls
AndroidPushServer       libpush.so
lxr:production wang$*
**2、I run java in command "java -Djava.library.path=/Users/wang/javaPrj/AndroidPushServer/out/production com/yuwan/androidpushserver/server", the error as follow:**
*lxr:AndroidPushServer wang$ java -Djava.library.path=/Users/wang/javaPrj/AndroidPushServer/out/production com/yuwan/androidpushserver/server

/Users/wang/javaPrj/AndroidPushServer/out/production

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no push in java.library.path

        ...

        at com.yuwan.androidpushserver.server.(server.java:13)

lxr:AndroidPushServer wang$*

**3、I set java.library.path in java code by call  System.setProperty("java.library.path", "/Users/wang/javaPrj/AndroidPushServer/out/production"), but still load fail**.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here for a sample code that uses JNI and IDEA:

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-D002/

You can find super simple source code here as well:

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-001/

And you can take a look at the movie that shows how to deal with JNI debugging within IntelliJ and CLion here:

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCE2aYTLqPQ8Qx8oTkOjjwSQ

Comment: System.load() works fine, but the System.loadLibrary() load failed, and i have tried three ways mentioned in my problem to solve it, but still failed.

Answer (score 0):

If you do System.loadLibrary("push") in mac os X it will load libpush.dylib not libpush.so. If you do System.load you can load any file name you want.